# html audio tag not displaying in chrome but visible in elements in console and working in firefox, why?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, html5-audio, display

I have this react component :

```
import translate from "@kpt/ui/providers/i18n/translateService";
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { IContentProps } from "applications/Training/Domain/ContentsInterface";

interface IAudioPlayerProps {
  content: IContentProps;
}

const AudioPlayer = ({ content }: IAudioPlayerProps) => {
  return (
    <Box height="100%" display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <audio id="audio" controls>
        <source src={content?.src} type={content?.mimeType} />
        <Typography>{translate("app.users.formations.browserAudioPlayerError")}</Typography>
      </audio>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

It works fine in firefox but does not show in chrome. 
The audio player is not displaying but when inspecting the console in the elements part, I can see it. 
It's like if it was visibility hidden but I checked the css and nothing is hidden. 
I tried to add a z-index with no success. 
I don't understand why the audio player is not displaying in chrome but has no issue in Firefox. 
I saw some old posts of people having the same issue with angular but did not see a solution for my case. 
Did anyone have a similar issue with react and found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the issue. 
I had to add a width and height so it displays in chrome. 
Height and width that was not needed in Firefox to display it.